# Iterate and display values from a ResultSet with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, thymeleaf

I am building a spring boot thymeleaf web application. The application is intended to give our users a way to view and maintain reference tables in our database. These reference tables are stored in their own 'references' database. The tables are used for lookups, hold values that are inputs into calculations in the main database etc.

As there are hundreds of reference tables I am opting not to map them to classes, instead getting the ResultSet metadata from the references database, use this to generate a list of tables and displaying it back to the user with thymeleaf.

I'm new to spring boot and thymeleaf but can't seem to find a way to iterate over the ResultSet to display the contents of the metadata. Is there a way to do this? It appears that ResultSet is generally iterated over with while loops that move the cursor with each loop, but thymeleaf seems to use for loops?

A solution is to iterate the ResultSet in the usual way and add each row to a List of a List of Objects, something that might resemble a db table e.g. `List<List<Object>>`, but I don't want to do that just to use thymeleaf. Plus the ResultSet has a bunch of useful information about expected Data types and properties of each table column which I could use later for validating any new records the user might add/modify through the application. Or is there a nicer way to represent a database table and its associated properties?

Comment: You mention you're option not to map them to classes as there are hundreds or reference tables. Are you planning on displaying all of these to the user at once? The usual way to represent the database table is to map the columns to object fields and add those to a model which is picked up by the thymeleaf template. Thymeleaf can then reference those fields through the getters and setters in the class.

Comment: Passing ResultSet to View is not a good idea. Rather you should try get results into generic List<Map> and send the list to View

Comment: Can't your metadata structure be mapped to a class (and then use class mapping)? By "hundreds of reference tables", are you referring to the metadata DB?

Comment: @Sam - Because we have hundreds of these tables I want to generate a page with a list of tables, then dynamically generate a page for each db table that will dynamically show the columns and records, then the end user can add or modify the records as they need. The idea is that we aren't tied to the design of each individual db table by mapping each table to a class, but rather we're using the db metadata to construct the representation of each table dynamically.

Comment: I see. Amits point would probably work. You could create a reusable Table class with a List<Map<String,String>> - with the Map key being the column name, and the value being the column value. Then the list would hold each row in the table. You'd then be able to pass the list to thyme leaf and render it. It'd be pretty complicated mapping the changes back to the database though. I'll have a look around for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display the result is by means of a `List<String>` for table header, and `List<List<String>>` for table rows.  You mentioned that you didn't want to do this just to use Thymeleaf, yet I'm not sure of a way to preserve the table properties for use when the user wants to modify a table content.

The `List<String>` for the table columns can be generated using the meta-data.  The code may looking something like this:

```
final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
final boolean hasResultSet = statement.execute(query);
final ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
final int count = metaData.getColumnCount();

final List<String> header = new ArrayList<>(count);
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    header.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
}
model.addAttribute("tableHeader", header);
```

The `List<List<String>>` can be created a request time, or iterated during template rendering.  To achieve the lazy loading I recommend something like this:

```
final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
final boolean hasResultSet = statement.execute(query);
final ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
final int count = metaData.getColumnCount();

model.addAttribute("tableContent", new LazyContextVariable<Iterable<List<String>>>() {
    @Override
    protected Iterable<List<String>> loadValue() {
        return () -> new Iterator<>() {
            private boolean loadedRow;

            {
                try {
                    loadedRow = resultSet.next();
                } catch (SQLException exception) {
                    loadedRow = false;
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return loadedRow;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> next() {
                if (!loadedRow) {
                    return new ArrayList<>(count);
                }
                try {
                    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(count);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                        list.add(resultSet.getString(i));
                    }
                    loadedRow = resultSet.next();
                    return list;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

The Thymelead template may look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="queryResult">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th th:each="header : ${tableHeader}">
                <th:block th:text="${header}"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="row : ${tableContent}">
            <td th:each="item : ${row}">
                <th:block th:text="${item}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```